# Problems Baking High Poly Normals Onto Low Poly Mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, normals, baking, normal-map

I am trying to bake a highpoly sculpt onto a lower poly mesh and this is how the bake turns out. I am using the cage method. And baking the proper (Non-Color) profile. The bust and hair seem to bake fine however you can see an obvious problem within the face and ears UV.

[image: Normal Map and Nodes]

I have checked and reset and flipped and flopped the normals every which way to test. As you can see they are all properly facing outwards on all three meshes (HighP, LowP, and Cage.) There are no overlaps between the cage and LP. There is no duplicate geometry or double verts. Everything seems fine yet I have this problem.
[image: Normals Facing Out]
[image: Result]
This is for a client and I have been working on this problem for two days already!

Comment: Is there a reason why you use a cage? Just wondering because the *Extrusion* bake setting does usually a good job. Does the cage cover both models completely?

Comment: hello, maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/